# dbConnect with R 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 --Error in as.integer(from) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'

Tags: r

Just updated to R 3.0 and updated all the packages, including DBI. To my surprise, a script that I often use stopped working.

I am unable to connect to a MySQL database using dbConnect. The code script instantly, so only a few lines will reproduce the problem

```
> require("RMySQL")
> m = dbDriver("MySQL")
> dbConnect(m, user = 'user', password = 'pass', dbname = 'dbname', host = 'localhost', client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

Error in as.integer(from) : 
cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'
Calls: dbConnect ... mysqlNewConnection -> isIdCurrent -> as -> asMethod
```

Also tried it as:

> dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'user', password = 'pass', dbname = 'dbname', host = 'localhost', client.flag = CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

but the same problem

Also tried removing other parameters, but the same issue from the dbDriver.

What changed in the DBI package with the latest update? How can I fix this?

I noticed that the DBI package is orphaned so don't know who to ask.

Comment: Still no solution to this. I had to revert back to R 2.15.3. Doesn't anybody else encounter this bug?

Comment: I am getting this same error with `RPostgreSQL_0.4` and `DBI_0.3.1` on R `3.1.2` and `3.1.1`.  Oddly, `RMySQL_0.10` gives no errors.  Has anyone successfully determined what causes this error?  Restarting the machine doesn't fix the problem, and re-starting the SQL server does not either.

Comment: @Zach: See my answer below.  Look at your package load order.  For some reason if RMySQL masks RPostgreSQL, then RPostgrSQL produces the above referenced error.

Comment: Good news, DBI is no longer orphaned, see https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with R 3.0.1 on ubuntu.

Installing the latest version of the RMySQL-package resolved the problem:

```
> install.pacakges("RMySQL")
```

Make sure to restart R after the installation.

Comment: Tried it when I posted this question and didn't work. Tried it again now and worked. Seems like they fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still digging into the issue, but I think I've identified multiple causes of this issue.  At their root, they all have to do with R expecting an S4 object but getting back an integer instead.  I believe these are generally a result of the connection failing to establish.

Why is it failing?  One thing I've noticed is that if you fail to close to many of your connections (~16 [see the number of maximum connections specified in the driver handle call] open) DBI won't/can't open a new connection.   Make sure you are calling `dbDisconnect` as needed.  Usually, this sort of problem results in a sensible error message, however sometimes results in the above referenced error. If possible access the DB through an abstraction layer, e.g. `dplyr` as some will monitor the db connections and kill them if they are inactive.  Whereas, AFIK if you open a connection in a function and the function breaks, you have no way to close the open connection unless you returned the driver object from your initial call to dbConnect.  In this case you have no choice but to restart your instance of R (possibly resetting your machine and clearing your workspace as well).

The other issue I recently encountered is that if RMySQL masks RPostgreSQL, then RPostgreSQL will fail.  The reverse does not appear to be the case, but because others have mentioned RPostgreSQL in here as showing the same error message, it seemed worthy of note.

**Update**

The latest version of RMySQL (0.10.1) seems to have finished off RPostgreSQL - RPostgreSQL now fails to work regardless of load order.  The same people working on RMySQL appear to be working on RPostgres (https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres) and this conflict appears to be a non-issue if using that package instead of RPostgreSQL.  Specifically, use `RPostgres::Postgres()` in the place of `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()` when specifying the driver in dbConnect.  Other packages, e.g. dplyr, currently assume RPostgreSQL, so this issue can still bite (but it seems a resolution is in the works (https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/28).

Comment: Any idea how RMySQL breaks RPostgreSQL, but not the other way around?

Comment: Oh, I thought I posted my response on this... but the short answer is, no - I don't.  The best I could do would be to speculate.

Comment: @Zach: Ping and warning not to update to RMySQL .10.1.  See **Update** above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I opened an issue in the RMySQL issue tracker, hopefully it will be fixed on CRAN soon! https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/28