# R not recognizing a 'numeric' column from MySQL. It is taking it as 'S4' type

Tags: mysql, r

I'm trying to connect to a database table and extract a field into R in order to plot a histogram on its data.

```
cr_score <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "select C_Score from custfile")
```

and this is showing the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Decimal MySQL column 0 imported as numeric
```

Sample for cr_score is:

```
cr_score
100000
0
0
100000
50000
0
30000
60000
0
56000
40000
20000
50000
0
34000
20000
20000
20000
20000
25000
```

I went ahead and tried to plot a histogram on the data of `cr_score` and it showed the following error:

```
Error in hist.default(cr_score) : 'x' must be numeric
```

When I checked for the `class(cr_score)` it showed the following:

```
> class(cr_score)
[1] "MySQLResult"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RMySQL"
```

I then tried to convert `cr_score` into `numeric` type in R:

`cr_score <- as.numeric(cr_score)`

But I received the following error:

```
Error in as.numeric(credit_score) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

How to resolve this situation and plot a histogram on the column?

(I've connected MySQL to R for the first time. So, am a beginner at this. Please help!)

Comment: Can you show a sample of the `cr_score`?

Comment: try dbGetQuery unstead of dbSendQuery

Comment: Can you also show the schema for custfile?

Comment: Added the sample. thanks.

Comment: @Batanichek tried dbGetQuery. Same error. And also when tried to convert to numeric with `as.numeric` it said can't coerce a `list` object to a `double` type.

Comment: @hrbrmstr sorry can't share the schema of the custfile entirely, but for `cr_score` column it is: `C_Score decimal(10,0)` in MySQL database.

Comment: May be there are problems with packages which you loaded? ( show what package you use) ( find this idea in [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821321/using-rmysql-interferes-with-rpostgresql))

Comment: @Batanichek I used package `RMySQL`

Comment: Which version of `RMySQL` and `DBI` you use?

Comment: @Batanichek `Database Interface and 'MySQL' Driver for R`: version 0.10.7